# What is the time complexity of 'ls' command when run on ext4 filesystem?

Tags: linux, redhat, ls, ext4

I have a couple hundred thousand files in one of the directory on a Redhat Linux server.

I need to execute `ls -t` to fetch the name of the last edited file and upload the filename to a database. Lately I have started facing problems as the number of files in the directory keeps growing  and want to know the time complexity of `'ls'` command when it is executed on ext4 filesystem.

Also, what is a better way to do it?

Comment: Whatever it is, it is not going to improve if you keep on adding more files. Rethink your problem. Create a directory per day or something.

Comment: Unfortunately there are organisation wide policies concerning retention and audit etc. which put a constraint on changing the structure of directories or other favorable changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are running on linux os, you can simply use [inotify tools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki). There are some very simple to use command line tools to monitor every change on the filesystem using the kernels `inotify` interface.

Example:

```
> inotifywait -m -e create -e modify test/ --format '%:e %f'
```

The above command waits endless (-m -> monitor ) for the event (-e ) create and modify of files inside `test/` which is a directory and outputs with the formatted string where `%e` is replaced with the event and `%f` is replaced with the created or modified filename.

if you now run in a separate shell some checks like:

```
> touch test/newfile1
> touch test/newfile2
> echo hallo > test/newfile2
```

The output of the command is:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established. 
CREATE newfile2
MODIFY newfile2
```

Quite easy to simply write the file name now to a database without reading the whole directory again.

Comment: I tried various solutions, this one works the best. Though Redhat doesn't come with inotify-tools, but i found it worth compiling.